# c# websockets - Keep sending messages every X seconds, while waiting for message received in same websocket

Tags: c#, websocket

everyone!

I want to send some data which is binded to timeline (so it's just a Dictionary<\DateTime, MyData>) every X second(doesn't matter), while client not says me to start sending it anew but from a different start time.

So, the scenario is kinda following

```
Client : Please, start send me data which is > DateTime1
Server: Sure! Catch! 
Server: <DateTime1, Data1>, 
Server: <DateTime1.AddSeconds(1), Data2>, 
..., 
Server: <DateTime1.AddSeconds(X), DataX>

Client : Please, start send me data which is > DateTime2
Server : Sure! Catch! 
Server: <DateTime2, Data1>, 
Server: <DateTime2.AddSeconds(1), Data2>, 
..., 
Server: <DateTime2.AddSeconds(X), DataX>
```

I understand how to send data via websockets every X seconds, but can't imagine how to wait for the client's new instructions in same time. So, any articles/ advices would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

UPD: Data sending code :

```
private async Task PushData(WebSocket webSocket, Dictionary<DateTime, List<Data>> dataPerSecond)
    {
        var dataPerSecondSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPerSecond);
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataPerSecondSerialized);

        await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes, 0, bytes.Length), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true,
            CancellationToken.None);
    }
```

and this method is called inside a while-loop with Thread.Sleep() after it.

Comment: Can you show your code for sending the data

Comment: Yep. Updated my question.